# fplot: anonymous function returns only zeros if limits not in specific range

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a csv-file with some integers stored in three columns

`trainData = load('training.csv')`

I want to count the occurences of a certain value within a certain range and plot the results.

```
count = @(x) (sum(trainData(:,2)==x));
fplot(count,[0,500]);
```

However this only works for certain limits and I can't figure out why. If the limits are not set "right", `count()` always returns zero.

this works, meaning the plot shows some values > 0:

- `fplot(count,[0,500]);`
- `fplot(count,[100,600]);`
- `fplot(count,[101, 601]);`
- `fplot(count,[200,700]);`
- `fplot(count,[50, 550]);`

The plot of [0,500]:
[image: 0 to 500]

This does not, meaning the line stays flat, even though there are definitely some y > 0 within this range (compare to previous plot):

- `fplot(count,[0,300]);`
- `fplot(count,[200,450]);`
- `fplot(count,[1,501]);`

The plot of [200, 450], oddly the value for f(250) is 1 and the rest is 0 :
[image: 200 to 450]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this strange behaviour was `fplot`'s way of picking values from the specified range of x-values. By default the step size is not 1 (which I assumed), nor does `fplot` use *all* possible values within the specified range (which would be probably impossible). Therefore my method did not find all values occuring in the csv (they were all integers). So the "working" examples from above did probably only hit *some* of the occuring values and the non-working example simply the starting value (plot of [200,450]), but not any other.

Briefly speaking, following solves the problem:

`fplot(count,[0,n], n);`

It evaluates the anonymous function for each integer in range `0` to `n`.